# Keeping folder permissions when using web deployment project?

Tags: .net, iis, web-deployment-project

I'm using a web deployment project to deploy a project on my local dev machine. Within this project I have a specific folder to receive uploaded files so the ASPNET machine account needs permissions to write to this folder. Unfortunately the web deployment process loses these permission each time I run it. Does anybody know of a way to keep these permissions?

I have tried setting them in both my development source folder and the folder in inetpub\wwwroot but neither seem to help.

Any ideas?